# Can i use both discrete Nvidia and integrated Intel HD at the same time for dual monitor?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

It is now 2016. and I've been wondering is it now possible to run simultaneously Intel HD 2500 and Nvidia GTX 650 Ti Boost on Ubuntu? I've set it up on Windows 7 after enabling iGPU support in BIOS and it's working great. I tried setting it up on Ubuntu and I ended up with crashed Ubuntu and had to reinstall it again.

When i run `lshw -C video` this is what i get:

```
    *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:e8000000-e9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

By the way, I'm using dual boot.

Just to be clear, I have two monitors with VGA port, one of them is attached to Nvidia card and another to VGA port on the motherboard.
I'm asking this because I've read answers which are 3,4 years old, and maybe developers found a solution for this.

Also, I'm running the latest 16.04 Ubuntu

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's possible if you run two different desktop environments on the separate displays. That is how I solved the problem on my laptop with a HDMI and direct port output (hdmi is hooked up to my nvidia card and the direct port is hooked up to the intel card). it's probably the same problem you have if you try to run a game with your nvidia card on the intel display on windows. Can you try to `export` a desktop session to the different displays?? These kind of changes reset after a reboot so it shouldn't need a reinstallation to reset.

Comment: btw, with this setup you will not be able to move windows between the different screens!!! (you may also need different input devices for the different desktops). You can also check this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors I know it's an old one but it might still help

Comment: I'm not sure how to run a different desktop environment, but I'l google it and try it out. Also I'm not interested in games, I only need two monitors for work.

Comment: bumblebee users had quite a bit of trouble with dual monitor setup. They fixed it by running 2 x sessions (two desktops), one would run from the intel card and the other from the nvidia card. A lot of tutorials exist because of this so try searching for bumblebee dual monitor and see if those solutions help. You will need a different way to run programs from your nvidia card than bumblebee uses (because desktops don't use optimus as far as I know) but I think the bumblebee solution can be adjusted to work with your system as well

Comment: @Cox Have you had any luck getting this setup to work?

Comment: @Dave No, I haven't actually. I bought HDMI to VGA adapter for a few bucks just to try it out, but no luck. For now I just have to deal with the fact that there is not a solution yet, or just buy a new monitor.